# Netilat Yadayim: Blessing Before or After?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, rambam, netilat-yadayim-washing, saadya-gaon

These may not be the original sources for either *shiTTah*, but two early examples of either of them can be found in the Rambam, [*Mishneh Thorah - Hilkhoth Berakhoth* 6:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2506.htm#2) (*mevorekh **batteHiloh***), and in the [*siddur* of Rav Saadia Gaon, *dinei berakhoth - ^amudh* 88](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=147) (***uv^aqav*** ghusl al-yadayin - *wa-**aHarei** reHiSath ha-yadhoyim*).

Essentially, the order for each method is:

1. **Rambam**: fill cup, say *berakhah*, pour water, and dry hands
2. **Rasag**: fill cup, pour water, say *berakhah*, and dry hands

My questions are:

- Which method is original?
- What is the source for each method?
- And mainly, with the general principle of making *berakhoth* before performing the *miSwah* (cf. [b.PesaHim 7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=7&format=pdf)-[b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=7b&format=pdf)), how can the second method be justified? And if it can be justified, does that make it original? (cf. first question)

Comment: There are Rishonim on both sides, so I don't know what you mean by "the source for each method". I also don't know how you intend to prove which is original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of your last question, two explanations are given by Tosafot ([Pesachim 7b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=7b&format=pdf)) as to why the blessing can/should be after washing:

> וכן בנטילת ידים לא חילקו בין נטילה של אחר בית הכסא דלא מצי לברך קודם מיהו בנטילה יש טעם אחר לברך אחר נטילה קודם ניגוב כדאמרינן (סוטה ד:) האוכל לחם בלא ניגוב ידים כאילו אוכל לחם טמא
>   [By] Neilat Yadayim they did not differentiate between the washing after leaving the restroom when one cannot bless before [and] an addition reason [in this case] to bless after washing before drying is as it says (Sotah 4b) "One who eats bread without drying his hands is as if he ate impure bread" [so drying is still considered part of the Mitzva].

Both opinions are cited in Shulchan Arukh (OC 158) and modern practices are varied.

Comment: +1 Good simple answer (although this shows it is so far back it's doubtful anyone would know which is older). This bracha did seem backwards, but at least its on good authority.

Comment: +1. Re "modern practices are varied": I haven't iirc heard of anyone saying the ברכה before washing. Who does that?

Comment: @msh210 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter for one, and I'm pretty sure one of my Teimani friends told me his family does too. (I can't say what's standard among Teimanim in general.) My point was just that it's still 'alive'.

Comment: @msh210 The *Bei'ur Halacha* considers this approach acceptable if the person's hands were clean prior to washing (e.g. he hadn't even touched a מקום מכוסה) and the washing area is in a clean location (158, s.v. מברך קודם נטילה). Subject to these conditions, he says, one should not object to someone who wishes to follow the approach that the Beit Yosef, Rambam, and Rabbeinu Chananel (and the Geonim who taught him) considered to be *l'chatchila*.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I am tre' curious about Rav Schachter saying the berakhah beforehand, but there does not seem to be a source in the wiki link you have provided. Is this a personal knowledge? Or is it written somewhere? Thanks. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Netilat_Yadayim_for_a_Meal#cite_note-23